# What is the use and meaning of the highlighted "and that" in this short text?

Tags: word-meaning

> So today we want to talk about the subject of defensive driving. And the way I define defensive driving is, the ability to develop the proper driving habits, so that we can compensate for pretty much anything that goes on out on the roadways **and that** we can avoid a crash at any level.

I want to translate it, and the use and meaning of it is somehow vague.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence in your paragraph explains **what** defensive driving is and **why** you might want it.  The **and that** you have highlighted, is giving more information as to what you would be able to do, if you were in a situation out on the road as described by the previous clause.

The sentence has several clauses which makes reading it slightly awkward.  I have rewritten the sentence below with some amendments:

> I define defensive driving as the ability to develop proper driving habits.  **Proper driving habits allow us to** compensate for pretty much anything that **happens** out on the roadways **so that we** can avoid an accident.

Does this help you with the meaning?

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is not a good example of proper English. A better version would have the following skeleton:

**[(so that) we can VERB and VERB]**

> "And the way I define defensive driving is the ability to develop
>   proper driving habits, so that **we can compensate** for pretty much
>   anything that goes on the roadways **and avoid** a crash at any
>   level."

All in all, the sentence has a lot of idiomatic and grammatical clumsiness. See Amblina's version for a better language model.